# Limiting table rows

Tags: mysql

How can I store only 10 rows in a MySQL table? The older rows should be deleted when a new row is added but only once the table has 10 rows.

Please help me

Comment: what query you need ??? Am not fetching i want to store only ten...

Comment: @somebody there's no need for a query. More to the point why?? I'm of the never delete anything school of thought. What happens if you need the information you're deleting in the future?

Comment: @triveni If any answer worked for you then go and click on the check box at the right of the that answer

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this with an [after insert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) trigger, delete the row where it is min date. e.g. DELETE FROM myTable WHERE myTimestamp = (SELECT MIN(myTimestamp) FROM myTable) but that could in theory delete multiple rows, depending on the granularity of your updates.

You could have an incrementing sequence, and always just delete the min of that sequence.

The question is why you'd want to do this though? It's a slightly unusual requirement.

A basic example (not validated/executed, I don't have mySQL on this particular machine) would look something like.

```
CREATE TRIGGER CycleOldPasswords AFTER INSERT ON UserPasswords FOR EACH ROW

    set @mycount = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UserPasswords up where up.UserId = NEW.UserId;

    if myCount >= 10 THEN
        DELETE FROM UserPasswords up where up.Timestamp = (SELECT min(upa Timestamp) FROM UserPasswords upa WHERE NEW.UserId = upa.UserId) AND NEW.UserId = up.UserId;
    END
END;
```

Comment: According to Jeff, you can keep every row, why do you want to remove olders ?

Comment: its a old password table when the user enters new password it should compare with old 10 rows if its present then that password should not change so...

Comment: I hope you're comparing hashes and not raw text passwords... So it is ten rows per user? I'd seriously consider a sequence number in that case, in the after insert trigger, delete the min of the sequence where user id = user id of inserted row. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Jeff Watkins can u give be a sample code or link for this please.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the last inserted id when your first row is inserted, and store it in a variable. When 10 rows are inserted, delete the row having id < id of the first inserted record. Please try it.

Answer (score 0):

first of all insert all values using your insert query
and then run this query

```
delete from table_name where (cond) order by id desc limit 10
```

must specify an id or time in one column